# Where should I bind a global event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I am wondering if I want to create a custom global event listener, where I should bind that event. Which one should I use?

```
$(window).trigger('someEvent');
```

or

```
$(document).trigger('someEvent');
```

or

```
$('body').trigger('someEvent');
```

For example, there is a site in which it has home, about-us, news and some other pages. Each pages has its own Javascript file, i.e. home.js, about-us.js.. and so on. And there's one common Javascript file, main.js, which serves all the core or common functions throughout the whole site.

Now I want to centralize all the `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).resize()` functions by triggering custom event in the main.js like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).trigger('documentReady');
});
```

and

```
$(window).resize(function(){
$(window).trigger('windowReszie');
});
```

And so all in all the Javascript files, they just need an `eventListener` for corresponding event, instead of repeating those `ready()` or `resize()` functions in every file.

But I am not sure if it's good to bind all those custom events into the same object. If yes, which object should I bind, window? document? body?

Comment: everyone of them works. But I wonder if there's any difference among them

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Could you give some detail about why you need a global event handler? Generally they should be avoided - this is why `live()` was deprecated from jQuery some time ago

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could use a **Publish/Subscribe** pattern which is an event-based way of thinking, but the **"events" aren't tied to a specific object**.

Your code will looks like this

*main.js*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.publish('documentReady');
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    $.publish('resize');
});
```

then, in the others .js you can simply subscribe:

```
$.subscribe('documentReady', function(){ alert('documentReady'); });
$.subscribe('resize', function(){ alert('resize'); });
```

The Publish/Subscribe pattern also allows you to create modular and reusable code, and plays an important role in creating better applications, loosely coupled, flexible, scalable and easy to test.

[THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/t7hrdvoy/3/) is a small working example of that code (i used [jquery-tiny-pubsub plugin](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-tiny-pubsub) for publish/subscribe methods, but you can use whatever you want)

Answer (score 0):

All of the above work but you should always try be as specific as you can to the component you are interacting with. Custom events don't need to be binded to a high level DOM elements as you are describing.

**Example:**

```
$('.slider').trigger('someEvent');
```