# Call jQuery Function From Any Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a `click` `JQuery` function in a global file so it can be used throughout my website so i don't have to keep repeating code.

Below is my file structure

```
|
|->index.html
|->index.JS
|->componentsFolder
   |
   |->page1Folder
      |->page1.html
      |->page1.js
   |->page2Folder
      |->page2.html
      |->page2.js
```

I tried adding the following in my index.js as this file is loaded in the `index.html` file and is loaded in all page but none seem to hit

```
$('body').delegate('button', 'click', function () {
    alert('click2')
});

$('.roundButton').on('click', function () {
    alert('click1')
})

$('button').click(function () {
    alert('click3')
})
```

This is the button HTML in my page2.html file

```
<button id="addReselNextButt" class="btn btn-info roundButton">Test</button>
```

This is at the very end of my `index.html` file and is where i load the index.js file and is loaded on every page so why doesn't it hit any of them, what am i doing wrong as the code i need to put in this will seem very repetitive across my 50pg website hence why i thought i'd be able put it globally somewhere and call it when needed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you call that from every page then you need to make the path relative to the root of the domain: `src="/index.js"`

Comment: And wrap in `$(function() { ... });` to execute at load time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857036/where-should-i-bind-a-global-event-in-jquery Could also use subscribe/unsubscribe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a file name helper.js and put your common jquery code in it 
and include it where you want

> make sure you include your jquery before include helper.js file